# nodeclipse only allows debugging of 1 .js file at a time

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

NodeClipse only allows debugging of 1 .js file at a time.
If I set a breakpoint in a different .js file the breakpoint is never hit.
Error is "source is not available".
NodeClipse is not able to load source of different files in the debug stack.
Maybe because I am running Current Version: v0.12.0 of Node.js because it used to work with an earlier version of Node.js.
I am also running Eclipse Luna SR2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Raise bug on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/ and give exact version of OS, Java, Node.js, Eclipse, Nodeclipse plugin and steps how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others that may see this post - and also, since tracing the threads through github can be confusing, here goes:

At this point in time, if you **revert back to Node v0.10**, nodelipse should be able to set your breakpoints properly.

```
$ node version
```

Going back to the problem, we can explore the problem by executing node-debug from the cmd line.

```
$ npm install -g node-inspector
$ node-debug --web-port 8181 --save-live-edit --no-preload yourApp.js
```

One can also observe the currently loaded JS files within the freshly generated V8_STANDALONE fileset in nodeclipse under the project view.  You'll notice that the files for the breakpoints you've set are not loaded.  When you revert back you'll see them show up so that should be a good indicator of node versioning compatibility as we all move forward with newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree the previous version of Node.js worked perfectly and debugging stopped working with the new version of Node.js

However, I was forced to upgrade to the new version  v0.12.2 because this version supports ExecSync to call Java Classes in a jar file synchronously instead of async.  But now ExecSync works but debugging does not.

Any suggestions on how I can debug with Eclipse with Node.js  v0.12.2?